# do I need to set up triplestore along with solr for external search in fedora commons?

Tags: solr, apache-camel, fuseki, fedora-commons

I have setup solr, camel-toolbox:fcrepo-indexing-solr and added the indexable property to the repository objects.
So, do I need to setup fuseki or sesame also or solr alone is just fine?

I am doing some transactions, creating new objects or updating. But I can't find any indexed objects in solr query page.

From netstat, I can see communication from 61616 (JMS port) 44863 & 44862 (camel-solr-indexing ports) and vice-versa.

But no communication to solr standalone server. So, I guess indexed objects are not being created in solr at all.

What am I missing here?

I can find two logs: transaction.log and velocity.log. I thought of getting information if there is any entry of the recent transaction I have done on fedora objects. But nothing I could find. And for your information, the velocity.log ends like this:

> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,230 - ResourceManager : found /views/mode-root.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,230 - ResourceManager : found /views/mode-root.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,231 - Could not load resource '/views/mode-repository.vsl' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader:
>   ClasspathResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource /views/mode-repository.vsl
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,231 - Could not load resource '/views/mode-repository.vsl' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader:
>   ClasspathResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource /views/mode-repository.vsl
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,231 - Could not load resource '/views/nt-base.vsl' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader: Classpat
>   hResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource /views/nt-base.vsl
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,231 - Could not load resource '/views/nt-base.vsl' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader: Classpat
>   hResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource /views/nt-base.vsl
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,232 - Could not load resource '/views/mix-created.vsl' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader: Clas
>   spathResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource /views/mix-created.vsl
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,232 - Could not load resource '/views/mix-created.vsl' from ResourceLoader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader: Clas
>   spathResourceLoader Error: cannot find resource /views/mix-created.vsl
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,235 - ResourceManager : found /views/jcr-nodetypes.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,235 - ResourceManager : found /views/jcr-nodetypes.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,238 - ResourceManager : found /views/node.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,238 - ResourceManager : found /views/node.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,241 - ResourceManager : found /views/fcr-versions.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,241 - ResourceManager : found /views/fcr-versions.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,243 - ResourceManager : found /views/fcr-fixity.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:25,243 - ResourceManager : found /views/fcr-fixity.vsl with loader org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader

and transaction.log only contains this:

> 2016-04-03 16:50:18,286 [main] INFO  com.arjuna.ats.arjuna - ARJUNA012163: Starting service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService on port 35848
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:18,298 [main] INFO  com.arjuna.ats.arjuna - ARJUNA012337: TransactionStatusManagerItem host: 127.0.0.1 port: 35848
>
> 2016-04-03 16:50:18,328 [main] INFO  com.arjuna.ats.arjuna - ARJUNA012170: TransactionStatusManager started on port 35848 and host 127.0.0.1 with service com.arjuna.ats
>
> .arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService

But no running service in netstat output on port 35848.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to make sure this solution was accessible to everyone else who might stumble upon it. This question was also posted by OP in the Fedora Community Google Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/fedora-community/triplestore/fedora-community/Fo4o98P_Tk4/H2WCGl8kEAAJ) and answered by members there.

To distill: They recommend using Apache Camel to capture Fedora Commons 4.x events and send content/updates to a search engine such as Solr. Solr would serve as the external search service for the Fedora Commons system. Finally, Karaf was recommended as a way to deploy Apache Camel.

I've quoted the answer below.

> You will find some information on this page under "Deployment": https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/FEDORA4x/Setup+Camel+Message+Integrations
>
> Basically, though, the first time you start Karaf, you use $KARAF_HOME/bin/karaf
>
> From within the console, you install the "service wrapper":
>
> $> feature:install wrapper 
>   $> wrapper:install
>
> Then, you can quit the karaf session (CTRL-d). From there, Karaf can be started either as a system service:
>
> ```
>     service karaf-service start
> ```
>
> or manually:
>
> ```
>     $KARAF_HOME/bin/karaf-service start
> ```
>
> Now, in order to connect to Karaf, you can either use SSH:
>
> ```
>     ssh -p8101 -lkaraf localhost (the default pw is 'karaf')
> ```
>
> or simply:
>
> ```
>     $KARAF_HOME/bin/client
> ```
>
> For more details, I would recommend the Karaf documentation: http://karaf.apache.org/documentation.html

Comment: Hi Hudson, thanks for posting the answer here. Yes, using karaf is recommended. But still some issues in the camel too. I have to try it again.